# How to stop unauthorized website replication/mirroring

Tags: nginx, security, reverse-proxy, vps, port-mirroring

I'm running a website in a vps server (nginx).  I recently found several other websites that are 100% duplicate of my website.

Even when I change a post or delete files from my server, these other websites automatically update with the changes I made!  It looks like someone has mirror website without authorization.  For this reason, its really hurt my SEO result.

Is this a reverse proxy attack? And how can I prevent someone from mirroring my website?

Comment: We would need to know the website addresses before we can tell.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to detect whether it's a mirror, reverse proxy or simply pointing to the same IP. Here's a little help for differential diagnosis and solutions based on the diagnosis.

1. **Mirror.** Probably not in this case, as you describe the changes are updating immediately. If it's a static version of your page, you should see from the logs when it has been mirrored and possibly block that IP. You could also create a Fail2ban rule for detecting unwanted mirroring.
2. **Reverse proxy**. Go to a random page like `http://example.com/7z2JhV986yM2` that hasn't been cached before. With `tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log | grep 7z2JhV986yM2` you should see the IP address used for retrieving the page to the proxy; might not be the same as the IP where the copy is located. Block that IP and see how the reverse proxy now gives `403`.
3. Another domain **pointing to your IP**. Simply `dig` for both hostnames and see the answers. This is not necessarily caused by hostile activities, but they could simply be remainings; domains of the former use of the same IP address that your VPS currently has.

   Do not serve the content of you page on every `Host:` header but only with your *canonical* hostname i.e. your domain. Use virtual servers i.e. [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) for that. You could either redirect everything else to the canonical hostname, which would actually improve your SEO, or you could give `error 404` or a placeholder page describing the domain is not in use.