# How to reproduce live mirror website

Tags: domain-name-system

I've just read this post: [How to stop unauthorized website replication/mirroring](https://serverfault.com/questions/883930/how-to-stop-unauthorized-website-replication-mirroring), and I think I'm in the case number3: we have a website (let's say example.com), and it seems that another website serves our pages under a different domain name.  (let's say bad.com)

The content in bad.com updates instantly, which makes me think the "attacker" just points his IP to my server. But I don't understand how that's possible, since on my server, my apache configuration doesn't allow for his domain name.

I've bought a fake domain name and tried to just change the dns to point
to the server's `example` dns, but that obviously doesn't work (I need to configure an apache virtualHost if I want to be able to use the domain name on a browser).

So how can I reproduce this? How does the "attacker" proceed? Is that a reverse proxy trick or something?

In other words, how do I setup apache (or how do I proceed in general) to make my website a.com serves the content of facebook.com (or any other website)?

Comment: You’d need to proxy the html pages, but you could use a redirect (302) for all other resources (images, JavaScript, css). That would save bandwidth on the bad server. You could also change the html on the fly to change e.g. <img src=“photo.jpg”> to <img src=“http://example.com/photo.jpg>.

Comment: side note: https://content-security-policy.com/

Answer (score 5):

With Apache it's a matter of a simple:

```
ProxyPass         /    https://example.com/
ProxyPassReverse  /    https://example.com/
ProxyPreserveHost off  # it's the default anyway
```

The trick is to replace `Host` header, so that example.com backend gets `Host: example.com` as it expects. It's a default behavior of Apache. For example haproxy doesn't do that, it leaves `Host: bad.com` by default.

Comment: awesome, apache is so cool... Thanks man, you saved my day.